# Angular Velocity and Calculation Issues

Tags: java, vector, simulation, physics, torque

So, my problem is that once a shape gets a substantial amount of angular momentum(anything visually noticeable), then the collision no longer works. It collides, slows down, but doesn't rebound as elasticity dictates, nor does it 'impulse' in one pass, instead gradually slowing down until it becomes stagnant.

```
public Vec2 getVelocityAt(Vec2 p) {
    return getLinearVelocity().add(new Vec2(-getAngularVelocity() * p.getY(), getAngularVelocity() * p.getX()));
}
```

I'm fairly certain the issue is directly related to the above code, I'm following the equations here: http://www.myphysicslab.com/collision.html

```
public boolean checkBounds() {
    if(bX1 == bX2 || bY1 == bY2) {
        return false;
    }
    double xa = 0D;
    double ya = 0D;
    int a = 0;
    boolean hC = false;
    double xn = 0D;
    double yn = 0D;
    for(double[] vertex : this.getShape().getVerticies()) {
        if(vertex[0] >= bX2) {
            xa += vertex[0];
            ya += vertex[1];
            a++;
            hC = true;
            xn -= 1D;
        }
        if(vertex[0] <= bX1) {
            xa += vertex[0];
            ya += vertex[1];
            a++;
            hC = true;
            xn += 1D;
        }
        if(vertex[1] >= bY2) {
            xa += vertex[0];
            ya += vertex[1];
            a++;
            hC = true;
            yn -= 1D;
        }
        if(vertex[1] <= bY1) {
            xa += vertex[0];
            ya += vertex[1];
            a++;
            hC = true;
            yn += 1D;
        }
    }
    if(hC) {
        Vec2 n = new Vec2(xn, yn).uscale();
        Vec2 cp = new Vec2(xa / a, ya / a);
        Vec2 rap = cp.sub(getShape().getCM());
        Vec2 va = getVelocityAt(rap);
        Vec2 rva = va;
        Vec2 rvb = Vec2.ZERO_VEC.sub(va);
        double pj = -(1D + getElasticity()) * rva.dot(n);
        double j = pj / (1 / getShape().getMass() + Math.pow(rap.cross(n), 2D) / getShape().getMass());
        applyForce(new AppliedForce(n.scale(j), rap, getShape().getMass()));
    }
    return hC;
}

public void applyForce(AppliedForce... f) {
    for(AppliedForce vec : f) {
        Vec2 a = vec.getForce().divide(getShape().getMass());
        applyLinearAcceleration(a);
        double aa = a.relativeCosine(getShape().getTangent(vec.getOffsetCM())) * a.getMagnitude() / getShape().getMass();
        applyAngularAcceleration(aa);
    }
}
```

If there is no angular velocity, then no issue occurs, and is pronounced more by higher angular velocity. I think the velocity at a point function is the root of the issue, but not certain as to why. I have done the debugging, not having found much, I assume it is a misunderstanding of the math. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at first formula in section *Physics of Collision for Rigid Bodies in 2 Dimensions* of page you linked to:

```
vap1 = va1 + ωa1 × rap
```

where rap is vector from center of mass to point p on body a, if this is what you are using then rap is not a tangent at p, rather you would want your `t = (p in world) - (CM in world)`.

Comment: But my angular velocity is a double, not a vector. It's an independent component. How I had it setup should be a cross product for it, or so I thought. Would I need to calculate linear velocity relative to the center of mass based on angular velocity?

Comment: sorry my mistake it's been too long since I've done a cross product :} Makes sense because you're in 2D so the angular vel is the z axis with norm equal to ang speed. I just looked more carefully and the way you do it is fine, so the problem is elsewhere. I have started over.

Comment: va1 is the linear velocity, and I'm crossing wa1 and rap1 in the code contained in the add statement. I think I'm subtracting in the wrong order for the rap though. EDIT: Oh. I'm a moron, thanks.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and the problem persists. p is relative the CM, but for some reason I thought I needed the tangent of it. Thoughts?

Comment: So the issue is indeed that the computation of t was wrong? I'm wondering now since your last comment indicates no but you accepted answer...

Comment: I thought it had fixed it, and indeed it was an issue, but it doesn't appear to be the only one.

Comment: Same problems as before? I can't see anything obvious, short of carefully verifying that your calculations match the ones on the website, I can't help more. You should be able to find define test scenarios that you can solve on paper (like collision at tip perpendicular to CM), and print out what code gets for those cases, maybe this will show some mistakes in your code, sorry can't do more.